# Disable FEC in WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, networking, webrtc, peerjs

I am trying to demonstrate different Forward Error Correction (FEC) methods through a WebRTC call - however, WebRTC already has pretty good error correction, which obscures the effects of the things I wish to test.

Is there any way to disable FEC on a WebRTC call? In particular, I am using PeerJS as my WebRTC API, and I'd hopefully be able to implement this with minimal changes to the PeerJS source code. Thanks!

Comment: You'd have to get a handle to the SDP in the callback to `RTCPeerConnection::offer` and modify it before setting local description. I don't think this is do-able with PeerJs, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Looking at PeerJs source, the actual offer/answer handshake with sdp is private, and not exposed via their APIs.